# Is there any Avid AudioVision (DAW) video online?

Tags: pro-tools, daw, video, resources

After reading [this thread](http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=11782) at the DUC (and chatting with editors in this business longer than me), I'm really curious to see Avid AudioVision and how it worked.

My first encounter with a Digidesign/Avid software was at a sound engineering course I took, and back then we had ProTools 5.1 (and that was the same version I used for the next 4 years, when I started working). I missed and still miss in ProTools 9, all those great feature that AudioVision seems to already have 15 years ago (Bin, clip based volume and EQ, integrated EDL autoconform, etc).

Is there any video online (or other resource) that show AudioVision and its workflow (it was more like Media Composer than Protools, right?): can't find any.

Comment: I worked on an AudioVision for a number of years -- I'm a picture editor, but we could only afford one machine -- since the MC didn't support audio cuts shorter than a frame, and the AudioVision could cut picture like a classic editor (straight cuts only -- the purest form of picture cutting) I was fine with that -- straight cuts only is how I roll. It really was a great machine -- on the audio side, my favorite was the pencil tool where we could redraw the sound wave to lessen the harshness of the sampling. It basically looked like a stripped down MC, clearly geared toward sound. I don't reme

Answer (score 2):

I guess Davide is referring to the AVID AUDIOVISION, which was Avid's DAW before they bought Digidesign and Pro Tools ruined it.

To answer your question first: I'm sorry, but I don't know any video online and just had a look and couldn't find any manual or stuff like that anymore. :-(
But I still know one or two studios who still have a working system. (But only for backup compatibility)

For me AudioVision was the first DAW I worked on. I learned everything film related on it and am happy to have done so, as I still think it was a lot more focused on EDITING sound and not just track laying and mixing.
E.g. you could select all the scene edits of a reel and then say you want a 2 frames crossfade centered on the cut. Not speaking of bins with subsequences (great for editing changes, or pasting the basic ambiences of a scene) or the clip editor for selecting the material and channels you need prior to putting it in the time line.
Also as you mentioned clipbased gain and a bunch of other features never made it into ProTolls though some were announced to make the transition.

But I can also say that with todays mixing, multichannel and Plug-In capabilities, I would not want to trade in a recent ProTools for an Audiovision. (Though for foley editing it should still be faster to get the job done - IMHO)

Let's see where the future development will lead us. As long as some people have not forgotten about the benefits of such a system the ideas are still vital. (hopefully)

Comment: Plus, Audiovision only worked with SD2 files- no WAV's or AIFF's. Was THE BEST EDITOR on the planet but definitely not worth trying to get a hold of one now. Wish all DAW developers would go back and look at the features and editing tools and try to integrate some of that into newer software.